# Use struct as wrapper in go

Tags: go, struct

How to wrap `redis.Client` to my `struct`? I have that code and gives me an error

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
)

var cache *RedisCache

// RedisCache struct
type RedisCache struct {
    *redis.Client
}

func initCache() *RedisCache {
    if cache == nil {
        cache = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
           Addr:     "localhost:6379",
            Password: "",
            DB:       0,
        })
    }

    return cache
}
```

```
cannot use redis.NewClient(&redis.Options literal) (type *redis.Client) as type *RedisCache in assignment
```

There is some method to convert that property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`redis.NewClient()` returns a value of type `*redis.Client`. Use a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) to create a value of your `RedisCache` which you can assign to `cache`:

```
func initCache() *RedisCache {
    if cache == nil {
        client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
            Addr:     "localhost:6379",
            Password: "",
            DB:       0,
        })
        cache = &RedisCache{Client: client}
    }

    return cache
}
```